# Regular expression for matching mail in text in c#

Tags: c#, regex, email

I have mail addresses in following format `sometext@mail.com` inside of some text. @mail.com is always in same format, and sometext is changing. How can I match sometext@mail.com inside of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not trivial, and you're liable to end of with incorrect matches in corner cases regardless of the regex you use, but as a first approximation, I would suggest

```
\b\S+@mail\.com\b
```

This will not match mail addresses that contain spaces, but it will handle punctuation around the address (as in `"(sometext@mail.com)"`) correctly.

Comment: Thank you. I am using it like  Match match = Regex.Match(contentBody, @"\b\S+@doguskalipltd\.com\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); but I am getting null

Comment: You need to escape your backslashes like this: "\\b\\S+@doguskalipltd\\.com\\b"

Comment: It can simply be escaped with the help of `@` before the string `(eg. @"fgfgf abc@mail.com fgfg")` @user1775603

Comment: @Vishal Suthar Thanks. Good to know. Haven't worked much with regex in c#.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need:

```
\b[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@mail\.com\b
```

***Edit:*** (I just tested it on my PC and it works)

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string body = "hgfhfghgfhfhh fdfdf@mail.com gfhhfhf";
Match match = Regex.Match(body, @"\b[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@mail\.com\b",
                          RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); 
if (match.Success) { 
    // Finally, we get the Group value and display it. 
    string key = match.Groups[1].Value; 
    Console.WriteLine(key); 
}
```

[Live Demo](http://regexr.com?33e3s)

Comment: Thank you. I am using it like Match match = Regex.Match(contentBody, @"\b[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@mail\.com\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); but I am getting null

Comment: I used it like  match.Value and it works :) Also I didn't include ^ and $ in pattern.